# Blacklist fonts for a specific program

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fonts, anti-aliasing

I am specifically interested in black-listing fonts for Google Chrome.

I don't like antialiased fonts for smaller sizes. When I'm using Firefox, I can prevent pages from rendering using the fonts specified by their authors, while also requiring that they use the fonts that look good, when not antialiased.

Google Chrome doesn't have a way of ignoring font-family attribute of loaded CSS.  I was hoping that using `fonts.conf` I could prevent Chrome from seeing the fonts installed on the system, which will not render well without antialiasing.  I've looked into [font-config manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html), but I don't see anything that'd help me there.